# C++ Builder Ambiguity Error Relating to 3rd Party Header Files

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm working on a large project, which uses many 3rd party libraries. Due to this fact, I've run into some ambiguity errors. Some functions are defined in the global name space and also in a different name space.

I'm know you can specify the "using" to say which namespace to use, however I don't know how to specify it for the file, without prepending "::" to each of the errors.

If anyone knows of a way, or has a better way, I'm all ears.

**Background:**

If I needed the non global namespace, it wouldn't be an issue, as I could use "using" with that name space... curious on if there is a way of doing "using" with a global name space reference

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to resolve the ambiguity without specifiying which namespace you want to take each function from.

Comment: if I needed the non global namespace, it wouldn't be an issue, as I could use "using" with that name space... curious on if there is a way of doing "using" with a global name space reference.

Comment: Sadly that reference is ::, I'm tried several things I can think of, however its looking for an identifier, so perhaps it is limited by the compiler? Kinda sucks if that is the case... will leave this open for a bit to see if anyone has other input.

Comment: I believe the linker requieres there be no ambiguity. You would need to rewrite your compiler, but then it would not be a C++ compiler, as you would have created your own custom language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases it helps to rearrange the headers, so the ones that use global namespace are in front-

Answer (score 1):

If you have two identically named and parameterized functions under two different namespaces, you cannot:

```
using namespace x;
using namespace y;
```

because when you compile you will get ambiguity errors.

Options are to prepend the functions with x:: or y:: or to scope the namespace:

```
int test( void )
{
   using namespace x;
}


int test1( void )
{
   using namespace y;
}
```

Of course this only works if you don't use both namespaces in a single function.

Update:
The only way to specify the 'global' namespace is to prepend function calls with ::

Comment: I agree with what you wrote. The ambiguity error happens when I'm trying to compile the project, so it doesn't go through. My question is how to specify the global name space by the "using namespace" command, so there is not ambiguity.